# Given a binary boolean formula, how to find primary/root operator?

Tags: python, logic, boolean

I have binary boolean functions as input strings and need an efficient way to find the "primary" or "root" operator. Some restrictions on the form of the formula are that there is only "and" and "or" operators and no negation. The input strings denote "and" operators as single a's and "or" operators as single o's. The elementary variables are the represented by upper case letters. I am working in python. For example,

s = "( ( A o B ) a C ) a D" ==> root = second 'a'

s = "( A o B ) a ( C o D )" ==> root = 'a'

Instead of setting up a binary tree to traverse I have decided to work directly with the formula for ease in other areas of the program. As well, I would like to avoid having to create a whole tree for the formula as it's only purpose would be finding the root. I was wondering if anyone had an efficient way to find the root?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a root, both subtree of the root must contain balanced set of parentheses.
So If you just iterate from left to right until you find the first operator when parentheses are balanced.

```
pcount = 0
for c in function_str:
    if c == '(': pcount += 1
    if c == ')': pcount -= 1
    if (c == 'a' or c == 'o') and pcount == 0: 
        return c # Root found
```

*I'm not 100% sure this will work in all cases since i thought of this just now. Do you see any cases this won't work?

Comment: If the parentheses are minimally formed (ie no extraneous sets) this works. If you have extras, ie s = "(( A o B ) a ( C o D ))", then it fails. Maybe keep a running lowest-found-pcount instead assuming the minimum must be 0?

Answer (score 0):

Like Hugh mentioned above, this modification to kefeizhou's code should cover all cases:

```
min_pcount, pcount = 10000, 0
root_node = '#'
for c in function_str:
    if c == '(': pcount += 1
    if c == ')': pcount -= 1
    if (c == 'a' or c == 'o'):
        if pcount < min_pcount:
            min_pcount = pcount
            root_node = c
return root_node
```